# How to get the correct date format?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Not being able to get the desired output.
The question is : Create a function that takes an input parameter type datetime and returns the date in the format MM/DD/YYYY. For example if I pass in ‘2006-11-21 23:34:05.920’, the output of the functions should be 11/21/2006

My SQL code :

```
CREATE FUNCTION CalculateDate(@InputDate DATETIME)
RETURNS DATE 
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CONVERT(varchar(10), @InputDate, 101)
END

SELECT dbo.CalculateDate('2006-11-21 23:34:05.920') AS [MM/DD/YYYY]
```

But on execution :

[image]

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: I just have to create a function. It doesn't refer to any dbms

Comment: @jarlh is asking which https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_relational_database_management_systems (DataBase Management System) you're using.  Examples : MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server, SQlite, Microsoft Access, Oracle, etc.

Comment: You want to return a string. You are returning a date: `RETURNS DATE`.

Comment: Oo sorry Microsoft SQL Server @jarlh.

Comment: It's not working even if I match the return type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A date does not have a format. `2006-11-21`, `21.11.2006`, `11/21/2006` are all representations of the same date (or can be).

When you are asked to write a function that returns a date in a certain format, you are asked to return a string. Your function, however, returns a `DATE`.

What happens in your function is that you convert the datetime to a date string and the DBMS converts that back to a `DATE`.

Change `REURNS DATE` to `RETURNS VARCHAR(10) hence:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CalculateDate(@InputDate DATETIME)
RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CONVERT(varchar(10), @InputDate, 101)
END
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f5cfdc7e1761ae6e370a6b4f51674813